# I want to replace Chrome OS with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

On one of your questionnaires, someone asked if they could replace the Chromebook Chrome OS with Ubuntu. Hershey said that Ubuntu 16.04 wouldn't work. Is that still true or is there an update to that? I'd like to do that.

Comment: Could you put a link to the question you refer to in your question? Use the edit button below the question. I have replaced Chrome OS with Ubuntu, currently at 16.04. Whether it works or not will depend on your Chromebook's hardware and firmware/BIOS.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It appears you tried to edit this question while not logged in. Please log into your user account when you want to edit your posts so they don’t have to go through review and it becomes clear that you, the original author, intends these changes. Thanks.

Comment: Who is "Hershey" and what did he/she/it say exactly?

Comment: OP probably meant this: https://askubuntu.com/a/898834/480481