# How to replace a Acer Chromebook with Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, chromebook

I have an Acer Chromebook with model-number CB3-132-C971 and it will be reach end of support in June 2022. I don't want to throw this computer away. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on this computer with an ISO-file?

How do I remove Chrome-OS totally and install Ubuntu instead? what are the steps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall chrome OS and install Ubuntu 16.04 fully (not Crouton) on a Chromebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898833/how-to-uninstall-chrome-os-and-install-ubuntu-16-04-fully-not-crouton-on-a-chr)

Answer (score 1):

first you backup your files and completely remove the chrome os by wiping the harddisk it can be done by using the disk management or during the installation of the ubuntu.Before that you should download and boot the ubuntu to pendrive using a software (Rufus is best in town). Then just restart your computer and go to the boot menu and boot from the pendrive and then install the ubuntu.During installation you can just erase disk and click install... Its that easy.... ;}